# Modifying values in a dictionary not working

Tags: python

```
alien_3 = {'x_position' : 0, 'y_position' : 25, 'speed' : 'medium'}
print ('Original x_position: ' + str(alien_3['x_position']))

# Move the alien to the right 
# Determin how far to move the alien on its current speed
if alien_3['speed'] == 'slow':
    x_increment = 1
elif alien_3['speed'] == 'medium':
    x_increment = 2
else:
    # This alien must be really fast
    x_increment = 3

# The new position is the old position plus the increment
alien_3['x_postion'] = alien_3['x_position'] + x_increment
print('New x_postion : ' + str(alien_3['x_position']))
```

So when i run this i don't get the incremented value i get

```
Original x_position: 0
New x_postion : 0
```

Comment: You have a typographical error `postion` should be `position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: you *get* `alien_3['x_position']` but you *set* `alien_3['x_postion']`, missing an `i`.

Note that this would be better expressed with `+=`, which would avoid the problem:

```
alien_3['x_position'] += x_increment
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo.

alien_3['x_postion'] = alien_3['x_position'] + x_increment

should be:

alien_3['x_position'] = alien_3['x_position'] + x_increment